# How do I get a Rectangle object in Java to bounce from one side of the JFrame to the other

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to create a space invaders game and so far I have the JFrame set up with the ship that the character controls using the left and right keys, I made a another class for the alien in which I create a Rectangle object and try and get it to move from one side of the JFrame to the other but it starts moving towards the left and it just goes of screen instead of changing direction. In the main JFrame class I created a static instance of the alien class where I created a Thread in the main method and started it just like I did with ship that the character controls. I will put my alien class below. I am new-ish to java and appreciate any help, thanks.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


public class Alien implements Runnable {

    int Alienx, xDirection;
    int y = 30;

    Rectangle Alien;

    public void run() {
        try{
            while(true) {
                move();
                Thread.sleep(30);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public Alien() {
        Alienx = 370;
        Alien = new Rectangle(Alienx, y, 15, 15);
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xdir) {
        xDirection = xdir;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(Alien.x, Alien.y, Alien.width, Alien.height);
    }

    public void move() {
        Alien.x += xDirection;
        if(Alien.x <= 0) {
            setXDirection(+1);
        }
        if(Alien.x <= 400) {
            setXDirection(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what, specifically, is the issue you're having difficulty with?

Comment: The rectangle was going of screen but I just realized my mistake.